# How to use self signed certificate with nginx on Windows for office add-in testing

Tags: docker, nginx, https, office-addins, self-signed-certificate

I would like to test development version of an [office 365 add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview) on Windows. I would like to serve the actual web content for the add-in with a local running docker image. The goal is to have a nginx docker serving the content. I use the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  addInServer:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./../dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - ./nginx/cert/ianew.crt:/etc/nginx/ianew.crt:ro
      - ./nginx/cert/ianew.key:/etc/nginx/ianew.key:ro
```

For configuration of nginx I use this single configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         localhost;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ianew.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ianew.key;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

I followed a lot of tutorials on how to create a self signed certificated in this question I would like to refer to the most promising one which I think is this: https://www.seoexpertstuff.com/create-self-signed-ssl-certificate-windows-openssl/

As you can see I used the files `ianew.crt` and `ianew.key` in my nginx config for HTTPS. I tried first to import `canew.crt` and later also tried to import `ianew.crt` through the file explorer. I also restarted the PC to be sure this is not the problem. Nothings works.

Edge browser still thinks the content served from the HTTPS endpoint is not secure and the office 365 add-in does not work at all. I presume for this reason.

Is there a key thing I have been missing? Maybe in the nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you import from explorer, you may imported into `Personal Store`.

Use this command to import root ca cert into `Root Store`

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "c:\demo\canew.crt" -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\Root
```

Use this command to check the root store

```
Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\AuthRoot | Where-Object { $_.Subject -match 'CN=Your Root Subject ' }
```

After import the root store, when you create csr file by command `req -new -key ianew.key -out ianew.csr`.

Input the `common name` as `localhost`
[image]